# Обработка нажатия клавиш для элемента, указанного мышью

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу игру с использованием JQuery. Требуется привязать функцию, для каждого элемента набора (в моём случае -- ячеек таблицы), активируемую при нажатии клавиши на клавиатуре, если курсор указывает на данный элемент. Например, при нажатии "A" удаляются все элементы, имеющие тот же класс, что и элемент, на который указывает курсор.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
     if(e.which == 65 /* Код кнопки А (латиница)*/){
      var $table = $("#table");
      var $active = $table.find("td:hover");
      if($active.length > 0){
       var code = parseInt($active.attr("data-key"));
       if(code > 0){
        $table.find('td[data-key="' + code + '"]').attr("data-key", 0);
        console.log(code);
       }
      }
     }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
}
table td {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #fff;
}
table td[data-key="0"] {
    background: #fff;
}
table td[data-key="1"] {
    background: #f00;
}
table td[data-key="2"] {
    background: #0f0;
}
table td[data-key="3"] {
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td data-key="0"></td>
        <td data-key="1"></td>
        <td data-key="3"></td>
        <td data-key="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-key="2"></td>
        <td data-key="1"></td>
        <td data-key="3"></td>
        <td data-key="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-key="3"></td>
        <td data-key="2"></td>
        <td data-key="0"></td>
        <td data-key="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-key="0"></td>
        <td data-key="1"></td>
        <td data-key="2"></td>
       <td data-key="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Для примера ячейки идентифицируются по `data-key`: `data-key = 0` - cпокойное состояние